# how can i use ngModel inside bindings of components angularjs

Tags: angularjs, binding, components

```
angular.module('RatingModule').component('starRating', {
    templateUrl: 'rating.html',
    controller: RatingCtrl,
    bindings: {
        maxStars: '=',
        ngModel : '='
```

//above is the component where i want to use ngModel inside bindings of coponents

```
function RatingCtrl() { i want to use ngModel here }
```

// below is the index.html where ng-model is binding a value from the app controller

```
<body ng-app="RatingModule" ng-controller="appCtrl as ctrl">
<star-rating ng-model="ctrl.rating.number" max-stars="5"></star-rating>
```

Answer (score 2):

> the angular ngModel directive binds an **input,select, textarea** (or
>   custom form control) to a property on the scope using
>   NgModelController, which is created and exposed by this directive.

This sould not work, plus you should not use a angular name for a custom property.

you can do

```
angular.module('RatingModule').component('starRating', {
    templateUrl: 'rating.html',
    controller: RatingCtrl,
    bindings: {
        maxStars: '=',
        myModel : '='
```

then

```
function RatingCtrl() { $scope.myModel }
```

and

```
<star-rating my-model="ctrl.rating.number" max-stars="5"></star-rating>
```

Comment: $scope is not defined ... and i want ngModel not myModel

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39014858/two-way-binding-not-working-in-component-angular-js-using-ngmodel
this is all the files needed... i need u to read again ,,, if u can help me plz
@DMCISSOKHO

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually it's possible to use ngModel, but it's 100% worthless.
You can set ng-model on component, then `require: 'ngModel'` and manually set `ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue` on 'click' for example. But as I said before, it's ill wrong approach.

**Here is a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/I8wYySQAQghB0l0uPdak?p=preview), basically, you can set model as you want**

```
element.on('click', function(){
    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(scope.index);
});
```

> $setViewValue(value, trigger); Update the view value.
>
> This method should be called when a control wants to change the view
>   value; typically, this is done from within a DOM event handler. For
>   example, the input directive calls it when the value of the input
>   changes and select calls it when an option is selected.

Comment: i don't need to use directive... my boss said to use a component for rating stars... i did the rating,,, but he wants me to put ng-model in the index.html so when someone reuse my component he can put the average rating and when he open the rating template a highlight on  the stars depend on the average ... for example he put ng-model="ctrl.rating.number" that equal to 4 and it exist on the base controller (not the controller of the component) so i need to use this ctrl.binding.number on the controller of the component...

Comment: @JoeSleiman Your boss is wrong. A reusable component shouldn't depend on an outside controller. It's also architecturally wrong to use controllers (body ng-controller) in a components based application. It looks like he wants a directive in a classical MVC app.

Comment: @JoeSleiman, I just wrote an example, how you can use ngModel. Component is just a wrapper around directive.

Comment: @Kindzoku 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39014858/two-way-binding-not-working-in-component-angular-js-using-ngmodel
this is all the files needed... i need u to read again ,,, if u can help me plz

Comment: Well, actually it's possible to use ngModel, but it's 100% worthless. - I would disagree, it would seem that many overlooks the secondary effect of integrating to ngModel controller rather than a regular binding. this includes ng-model-options, validation pipeline and formatter/parser pipeline etc.

Comment: Well, actually I can't remember why I wrote this. Maybe I meant that using ngModelController for such an easy task is overkill. Can't remember for sure. But generally, ofc, using of ngModelController not worthless at all.

Answer (score -1):

DMCISSOKHO raised a good point, you couldn't use ng-model here. Try this instead:

```
angular.module('RatingModule').component('starRating', {
    templateUrl: 'rating.html',
    controller: RatingCtrl,
    bindings: {
        maxStars: '=',
        ratingNumber : '='
```

and in your view use

```
<star-rating rating-number="ctrl.rating.number" max-stars="5"></star-rating>
```

Comment: Isn't that the same answer as @dmcissokho ?

Comment: my boss want to use ng-model and bing it to the controller of the component (i'm training stage)
bindings : {
              ngModel : '='
    }

Comment: @m0rjjj, you duplicated DMCISSOKHO's answer. Just changed an attr name.

Comment: @Kindzoku not my answer ;)

Comment: @gyc, yeah, sorry :D

Comment: @m0rjjj
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39014858/two-way-binding-not-working-in-component-angular-js-using-ngmodel
this is all the files needed... i need u to read again ,,, if u can help me plz